# No arc in expression blend 5?

Tags: expression-blend-5

Is it just me or are there no arc shapes in expression blend 5? Why would they remove this shape, I found it super useful in a lot of projects. Do i maybe have to download a library?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is a library on nuget that has this if anyone else is looking

http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/